# how to backup postgresql database automatically on daily basis?

Tags: windows, postgresql, database-backups

I just want to know how to do backup of postgresql database on daily basis automatically?

Can someone share the complete process with me
I am new to postgres and want to learn database backup, i know how to do it manually but is there is any way so that i schedule the database backup process on daily basis.?

Answer (score 7):

Your can do the following: create a file `backupDB.sh`

**Windows version**

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
set BACKUP_FILE=BackupDB_%datestr%.bck
SET PGPASSWORD=<PassWord>
echo on
pg_dump -h <HostName> -p 5432 -U <UserName> -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% <DATABASENAME>
```

and then use Windows Task Scheduler

**Linux version**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
PGPASSWORD="**_PASSWORD_**" pg_dump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 -U **_USERNAME_** --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "DB_backup_$date.bck" **_DBNAME_**
```

To run this every day - lets say at 1:00 - you can use `cron`

```
crontab -e
```

contab entry:

```
0 1 * * *   ./backupDB.sh
```

Hope that helps

Comment: hey, thanks for your help, will get back to you after running these, i think it's for ubuntu but i am working on window. Any major change which i have to do to run it in window? I will create a batch file of above and schedule a task through window task scheduler.  Will this approach works?

Comment: And then daily back up the pg_dump to the cloud or somewhere off site

Comment: Updated answer, added a windows script version

Comment: It is better to add some more details.